# Download a file from an url into sdk card

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on phonegap with android project. i want to download a file from url into my sdk card.

**this is my Downloader.java**

```
package com.example.pgplugins.downloaderPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.phonegap.DroidGap;
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Downloader extends Plugin{

 @Override
 public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
 if (action.equals("downloadFile")) {
 try {
 return this.downloadUrl(args.getString(0),args.getString(1),args.getString(2),args.getString(3));
 } catch (JSONException e) {
 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Param errrors");
 }
 }
 else {
 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
 }

 }

 private PluginResult downloadUrl(String fileUrl, String dirName, String fileName, String overwrite){
 try{
 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "DIRECTORY CALLED /sdcard/"+dirName+" created");
 File dir =     new File("/sdcard/"+dirName);
 if(!dir.exists()){
 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "directory /sdcard/"+dirName+" created");
 dir.mkdirs();
 }

 File file = new File("/sdcard/"+dirName+fileName);

 if(overwrite.equals("false") && file.exists()){
 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "File already exist");
 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "exist");
 }

 URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
 HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 ucon.setRequestMethod("GET");
 ucon.setDoOutput(true);
 ucon.connect();

 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "download begining");

 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "download url:" + url);

 InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

 int len1 = 0;

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

 while ( (len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
 fos.write(buffer,0, len1);
 }

 fos.close();

 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "Download complete in" + fileName);

 } catch (IOException e) {

 Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "Error: " + e);
 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Error: " + e);

 }

 return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, fileName);

 }

}
```

**this is my Downloader.js**

```
function Downloader() {

}

Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl,dirName,fileName,overwrite,win,fail) {
 if(overwrite==false) overwrite="false";
 else overwrite="true";
 PhoneGap.exec(win, fail, "Downloader", "downloadFile", [fileUrl,dirName,fileName,overwrite]);

};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
 PhoneGap.addPlugin("downloader", new Downloader());
 PluginManager.addService("Downloader","com.example.pgplugins.downloaderPlugin.Downloader");
});
```

**this is my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.2.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- CDN Respositories: For production, replace lines above with these uncommented minified versions -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>-->
    script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="downloader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 window.plugins.downloader.downloadFile("http://www.toforge.com/archive.zip","sdcard/cache/","archive.zip", false,
 function(data){
 if(data=="exist"){
 alert("File already exist");
 }
 else{
 alert("File saved on sd card")
 }
 },function(data){ alert("error: "+data); });

 </script>
    </head>
  <body onload="init();">

  </body>
</html>
```

whenever i run that program, this error occurred, means no result is getting by me.

error:- **FORCE TO CLOSE THE PROGRAM**.

my program is not running.means before starting the run a halt is occurred. please check my code and help me to find out the error.

Comment: this the error whiich is occurred in logcat:-     07-26 16:48:55.328: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(275): Shutting down VM
07-26 16:48:55.328: WARN/dalvikvm(275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-26 16:48:55.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 16:48:55.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Comment: means before doing any function it stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If want to download the file in background using the services with notification then please check this out [android: file download in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787910/android-file-download-in-background)

I hope this will help you.